# I have this TypeError : Unsupported operand type(s ) for +: 'int' and 'function'

Tags: python, function, integer, typeerror

```py
import random

def deal_card():
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    card = random.choice(cards)
    return card


user_cards = []
computer_cards = []

for _ in range(2):
    user_cards.append(deal_card)
    computer_cards.append(deal_card)



def calculate_score(cards):
    if sum(cards) ==21 and len(cards) == 2:
        return 0

    if 11 in cards and sum(cards) > 21:
        cards.remove(11)
        cards.append(1)

    return sum(cards)



user_score = calculate_score(user_cards)
computer_score = calculate_score(computer_cards)

print(user_score)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: `user_cards.append(deal_card())` and `computer_cards.append(deal_card())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
user_cards.append(deal_card)
computer_cards.append(deal_card)
```

These lines caused trouble.

You appended the *function* `deal_card`, instead of the value calling the function will return (`deal_card()`).

When the line `sum(cards)` ran, Python tried to add `deal_card` (the function) with a number. This will cause an error.

Change `.append(deal_card)` to `.append(deal_card())` should solve your issue.